# Passing selected date from Kendo UI DateTimePicker to moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, momentjs, datetimepicker

I am using a Kendo UI DateTimePicker which returns a selected date in this format:

```
Thu Dec 15 2016 23:23:30 GMT-0500
```

My goal is to pass this date into moment.js like this to get the day:

```
var momentDate = moment(selectedDate);
var moneyDayStr = momentDate.format('dddd');
```

However, momentDate just ends up being default to today's date since selectedDate is considered an invalid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there moment already make it deprecated with good reason  that they making construction using a non-iso string is deprecated check it [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

Therefore use `kendo.parseDate(date,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")` to format it to iso string first as i try it [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/UbAWE).

Comment: What is the fffZ part and why is it the correct thing to use?

Comment: i've read it somewhere on kendo forum. it is ISO 8601 string format